# Is it worth moving a small `std::vector<POD>`?

Tags: c++, vector, move

If you have a small (say, < 10 elements) `std::vector<T>` of PODs, is there much benefit to using `std::move()`?

In a codebase I'm looking at, I see a lot of code like this:

```
std::vector<double> temp{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};

class some_class {
 public:
   some_class(const std::vector<double>& _vals) : vals{_vals} {}

 private:
   std::vector<double> vals; 
}

some_class{temp};

// temp is never used again afterwards
```

I'm wondering if there's much benefit to changing it to this?

```
std::vector<double> temp{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};

class some_class {
 public:
   some_class(std::vector<double>&& _vals) : vals{std::move(_vals)} {}

 private:
   std::vector<double> vals; 
}

some_class{std::move(temp)};

// temp is never used again afterwards
```

Comment: It should be `some_class(std::vector<double>&& _vals)`, otherwise it can break the code like `some_class{temp};` with an unexpected object `temp` state after the call.

Comment: @273K oh good point. I also recall seeing a source before that said it might be better to just leave it as `some_class(std::vector<double> _vals)` and let the compiler figure out what to do?

Comment: Have you measured it?

Comment: @MrTux No. I just wanted to see if this is something that might be commonly known for really small vectors. I could measure it, but I presume the difference is so small that it probably won't justify me spending a few hours tracking down every site this is done in

Comment: Are you aware that after the initial move, `temp` would be in some "unspecified but valid state"? Would that result in a problem in the rest of the program?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think so because `temp` is never used again

Comment: Instead of `some_class{std::move(temp)}` couldn't you have `some_class{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0}}` (and get rid of `temp`)?

Comment: @Artyer I think that might reduce readability in the codebase at the callsite. (note `temp` is usually a name that's more descriptive). with that said, if do use `some_class{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0}}`, then is it better to use `some_class(std::vector<double>&& _vals)` or `some_class(std::vector<double> _vals)`?

Comment: If `temp` is never used again, consider scoping it so that it can never be used again. Better to get a compiler error than have to spend hours debugging if somehow it IS used again.

Comment: I'd say it depends whether you do it once an hour or several times a second.

Answer (score 3):

Using move semantics will likely avoid an extra allocation, which may or may not be considered significant in your domain. I doubt that copying of the elements itself is significant.

`const std::vector<double>&` can't be replaced by `std::vector<double>&&` because then the class becomes unusable with lvalue arguments.

It is possible to defined both overloads, but usually taking by-value and then moving into the member is sufficient. It may cost one extra move operation compared to two reference overloads, which is insignificant for `std::vector`:

```
some_class(std::vector<double> _vals) : vals{std::move(_vals)} {}
```

Then the user of the class can move into the constructor if that makes sense in the program logic at the call site:

```
some_class{std::move(temp)};
```

(Although the above line creates and immediately destroys a temporary object, which probably doesn't make much sense to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your variable declarations from

```
std::vector<double> temp{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};
```

to any of these (whichever is better for you):

```
static const auto temp = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};
static const std::initializer_list<double> temp = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};
constexpr auto temp = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};
constexpr std::initializer_list<double> temp = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0};
```

In this case when you will use this variable in expression

```
some_class{temp};
```

it will compile to basically same code as if you did

```
some_class{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0}};
```